# Android XML Parser only getting last entry

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to Parse an XML file into a List, however it is only getting the last entry in the XML file. I have a sample below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stops>
<stop>
    <number>stop_code</number>
    <lat>stop_lat</lat>
    <lon>stop_lon</lon>
    <name>stop_name</name>
</stop>
<stop>
    <number>112112</number>
    <lat>  51.060931</lat>
    <lon>-114.065158</lon>
    <name>"CRESCENT HEIGHTS HIGH SCHOOL"</name>
</stop>
<stop>
    <number>2110</number>
    <lat>  51.082803</lat>
    <lon>-114.214888</lon>
    <name>"EB CAN OLYMPIC RD@OLYMPIC CE ENTR"</name>
</stop>
    .....
    <stop>
    <number>9988</number>
    <lat>  51.047388</lat>
    <lon>-114.067770</lon>
    <name>"NB 2 ST@6 AV SW"</name>
</stop>
<stop>
    <number>9998</number>
    <lat>  50.997509</lat>
    <lon>-114.013415</lon>
    <name>"19 St @ 62 Ave SE nb ns"</name>
</stop>
```

And my pull parser is

```
ublic class PullParser {
public static final String STOP_NAME = "name";
public static final String STOP_LAT = "lat";
public static final String STOP_LON = "lon";
public static final String NUMBER = "number";

private Stops currentStop = null;
private String currentTag= null;
List<Stops> stops = new ArrayList<Stops>();

public List<Stops> parseXML (Context context) {
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stops_xml);
        xpp.setInput(stream,null);

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                handleStartTag(xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                currentTag = null;
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                handleText(xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return stops;
}
private void handleText(String text) {
    String xmlText = text;
    if (currentStop != null && currentTag != null) {
        if (currentTag.equals(STOP_NAME)) {
            currentStop.setName(xmlText);
        }
        else if (currentTag.equals(STOP_LAT)) {
            currentStop.setLat(xmlText);
        }
        else if (currentTag.equals(STOP_LON)) {
            currentStop.setLon(xmlText);
        }
        else if (currentTag.equals(NUMBER)) {
            currentStop.setNumber(xmlText);
        }
    }
}

private void handleStartTag(String name) {
    if (name.equals("stop")) {
        currentStop = new Stops();
        stops.add(currentStop);
    }
    else {
        currentTag = name;
    }
}
}
```

When I run this it only returns a stop number of 9998 for all 5882 entries (That is the correct number of entries in the file). Any thing obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyXmlPullParser objMyXmlPullParser = new MyXmlPullParser(context);
                        List<Map<String , String>> list = objMyXmlPullParser.readXml("Xml respose put here", "Table");



public class MyXmlPullParser 
{
    Context _context ;

    public MyXmlPullParser(Context _context)
    {
        this._context = _context ;
    }

    public List<Map<String , String>> readXml(String XmlString , String ParentTag)
    {
        Map<String , String > map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<Map<String , String >> list = new ArrayList<Map<String , String >>();

        try 
        {
            String Tag = "" ;
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(new StringReader (XmlString));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (true) 
            {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                {
                    Tag = xpp.getName();
                } 
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
                {
                    Tag = "" ;
                    if(xpp.getName().equals(ParentTag))
                    {   
                        list.add(map);
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) 
                {
                    String text = xpp.getText();
                    if(!Tag.equals("") && !Tag.equals(ParentTag)) 
                    {
                        map.put(Tag, text);
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
                {
                    System.out.println("End document");
                    break ;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        }

        catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
        {
            Log.e("xml reader" , "error in parsing  xml");
            return null ;
        }
        catch (IOException e)  
        {
            Log.e("xml reader" , "error in IO in xml");
            return null ;
        }
        return list ;
    }
```

Hope it may helps you